# How do I setup vue.config.js with typescript?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, webpack

Hello I am working with typescript for the first time and when trying to configure vue.config.js

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        __VUE_I18N_FULL_INSTALL__: true,
        __VUE_I18N_LEGACY_API__: false,
        __VUE_I18N_PROD_DEVTOOLS__: false,
        __INTLIFY_PROD_DEVTOOLS__: false,
      }),
    ],
  },
};
```

I am getting an error

```
$ vue-cli-service lint
error: Require statement not part of import statement (@typescript-eslint/no-var-requires) at vue.config.js:1:17:
> 1 | const webpack = require("webpack");
    |                 ^
```

When creating a js project, everything worked. How can I fix it in ts project

Comment: The rule says you can't use require, so you use import instead.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy require and import aren't easily interchangeable in .js Node files.

Comment: It's linter rule. This isn't directly linked to TS or Vue config. The rule can be disabled if it's unwanted (require has its uses in TS app), or config files can be excluded from linter run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Estus, it was an ESLint error, not sure why, but ESLint is throwing a typescript syntax error in the js file.
The solution is

```
/* eslint @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires: "off" */
const webpack = require("webpack");
```